# Raiden network and publicity

Tags: private-blockchain, plasma, sidechain, raiden

As I understand, privacy on of the key features or Raiden.

Let's say that I want fast transactions but at the same time I want to have the transparent transactions history for an independent observer, like on the main network.

Should I go with a Plasma in that case or theirs some way I can handle it with Raiden or other off-chain solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would say plasma. Plasma is a more elegant solution.